# Regex equivalent of *?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I want to translate the current regex:

```
(.*?)<w:t([^>]*)>
```

without using `*?` (in ActionScript3)

meaning I want to get everything before the first occurence of `<w:t`

I could use `([^<]*)`, but the problem is I want to match for example `<w:r` inside the first parenthisis.

Is it possible to do it with a regex or must I do it by hand ?

Comment: edit: retracting comment.

Comment: problem with .* is that it doesn't stop at the first occurence of <w:t

Comment: the "?" shouldn't be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised AS3 wouldn't support non-greediness! However I know at least that AS3 fully supports lookhead assertions, meaning you can do this:

```
((?:.(?!<w:t))*)
```

What this does is capture each character, one by one, as long as the character is not followed by a `<w:t`.

Careful not to flip the `!<` as `<!` or you'll inadvertently be asserting a look*behind* condition!

**EDIT**

Hm, AS3 *should* support non-greediness. I suspect your problem is elsewhere. For example, perhaps there's something wrong with the *remainder* of your regular expression, causing it to not match the "first" instance, causing it to "keep looking" until a subsequent instance that *does* match.

Comment: You're right, the regex still doesn't work. As I didn't know lookahead assertions, this helps me anyway, I'm going to use this for the whole regex.